# How to create a segue from the disclosure indicator on a table view to another viewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue

Is it possible to do that?

It appears impossible to drag from the disclosure indicator on a tableViewCell prototype to a viewController to create a segue.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you drag from the view controller to the tableViewCell it should offer you options 'cell selection' or 'accessory action'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

control + click on disclosure indicator connect to viewController you will get a menu like this

[image]

select the accessory action