# Connect UITableViewCell.xib with Disclosure Indicator to a view in Main StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a Table View Cell with disclosure indicator in a UITableViewCell named DeviceTableCell.xib. How do I connect it to a view in my Main StoryBoard when the user taps the > icon?

Comment: Are you trying to load a new ViewController/Custom View on tap of the disclosure indicator (>). If YES && STORYBOARDS then use Segues. if NIB files, load using awakeFromNib or pushViewController.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not yet familiar in coding with iOS.

Comment: You might be looking for this 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26012063/5252706

Comment: But my custom view is not in the storyboard. I created a different xib file.

Comment: Upon tapping on the UITableViewCell, you will get a callback on didSelectRow atIndexPath:, write your code of loading the new view there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to figure how to code it.